# Quantifying the impact of multiple time series on another time series

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, arima, intervention-analysis, dynamic-regression

I have a few time series that correspond to the popularity of various documentaries about food, and other time series that correspond to outcomes of interest (various dimensions of food consumption). This data is available both at a national (U.S.) level and, for some outcomes, broken down by region as well.

The popularity of the six documentaries peaks in 2011, 2015, 2017, and 2019 respectively (there are two pairs that overlap). We’ll likely cut off the time series at the onset of COVID in March 2020. The outcome data is either on a weekly or monthly basis: so if starting in 2011, the total number of timepoints is around 110 for monthly and 440 for weekly.

The research question is: to what extent did these documentaries have any impact on our metrics of interest? For some of these documentaries, there are many anecdotal reports indicating impacts on behavior, but no rigorous analysis yet on to what extent they shifted food consumption.

Does anyone have any suggestions on relevant techniques or resources? We are also thinking about how to do this in a pre-registered manner, as well as the assumptions necessary for causality as opposed to simply establishing an association. I am currently looking into dynamic regression (multiple regression with ARIMA errors, where the exogenous variables are the time series corresponding to the popularity of the documentaries) and interrupted time series / event study (where we would just use the release dates to define the pre- and post- intervention time series, though some documentaries are released multiple times on different platforms).
Below is a picture of one of the outcomes and the exogenous variables. The vertical black lines correspond to December, which highlights the seasonal trends we need to adjust for (via e.g. seasonal differencing).
[image]